# django inline formset with same parent and child model

Tags: django

I have a Person model which has a `parent` field which is foreign key to itself, so any instance of this model can have a parent which is another instance of the same model.

What I am trying to achieve is to add/update children of a Person using the inlineformsets provided by django. However issue I am having is that inlineformset requires different parent and child models.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class FamilyMember(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    job = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',
                               blank=True,
                               null=True,
                               related_name='children',
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
def add_child(request):
    member = FamilyMember.objects.get(name="Tom")
    child_formset_factory = inlineformset_factory(FamilyMember, FamilyMember, fields=('parent',))

    formset = child_formset_factory(instance=member)
    return render(request, "family/add_child.html", {"formset": formset})
```

**template.py**

```
{% block content %}
<form method="post">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

After inspecting the html I see fields are being rendered as `hidden`, which I am not sure why.

When i render this formset I do not see any children listed for any existing person, even when there are valid records in the db.

Instead what I would like to see is this, lets say if a person X has 3 children A, B, C, then I would like to have 3 dropdowns, first dropdown should have A as selected value, second should have B as selected and so on.

I am not sure if I am doing it the right way or if inlineformsets can work for this particular case.

Comment: set `fields=('name', 'age', 'job')` on the formset_factory. The fields are the field to edit in the form, that can't be the parent. You can add `fk_name='parent'` but it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @dirkgroten no that is not my question, I don't want to change 'name' or 'age' instead i would like to add children to a parent, meaning connecting some already existing person as child to some other person who already exists in the db, and at the same time want to show the existing children. Not sure how adding the `fields=('name', 'age', 'job')` solves it

Comment: please show template

Comment: @HenryM just updated.

Comment: but that's the purpose of a formset, create/modify new instances. If you just want to select the `parent` for an existing child, just use a normal model form where the `parent` field will be a dropdown of all possible parents. use a custom `ModelChoiceField` to modify `label_for_instance()` and show more than just the default `__str__()` for each instance.

Comment: ah you're doing the reverse relationship. Then a plain formset can be used with a form containing just one field (`ModelChoiceField`), where you initialise with the current children.

Comment: @dirkgroten can you please provide some example code.